# Count inner many to many field Django

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have following models:

```
class Analysis(Model):
    experts = ManyToManyField(Expert,
                              related_name='analysis',
                              through='AnalysisExpert')


class AnalysisExpert(Model):
    analysis = ForeignKey(Analysis)
    expert = ForeignKey(Expert

    questions = ManyToManyField(Question, through='ExpertQuestion')

class ExpertQuestion(Model):
    expert = ForeignKey(AnalysisExpert, related_name="expert_comparisons")

    question = ForeignKey('Question')
```

It looks like I have nested ManyToManyField. Analysis - > Experts -> Questions

What is the most efficient way to calculate number of questions for certain Analysis?

Comment: Are you missing the `Expert` model in your example code, or did you accidentally refer to `Expert` in you `Analysis` model?

Comment: I use it, but it doesn't contain important info concerning this problem. User can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate number of questions for single Analysis object using values_list.

```
analysis_obj.experts.all().values_list("question").count()
```

Above query tested on below models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Expert(models.Model):
    question = models.ManyToManyField(Question,
                              related_name='questions')

class Analysis(models.Model):
    experts = models.ManyToManyField(Expert,
                     related_name='analysis')
```

Comment: Did you test it? It doesn't work. Can't resolve keyword question into field.

Comment: Yes, can you please update your questions with expert and question models I will retest.

Comment: @AndrewFount updated my answer with my models, if you post your `Expert` model in you `Analysis` model and `question` model i will re test with your models

Comment: Question if like yours. Instead of Expert use User.